# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'headers') when calling ConsentHandler.HandleException

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-graph-api

I am making a call to get user details from the Microsoft Graph API in a Blazor server application.

To ensure the token is up to date I am catching any exception and passing this to the ConsentHandler.HandleExcpetion as per the instructions here https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access#in-blazor-server

```
@code {
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    Microsoft.Graph.User? user;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            user = await GraphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            ConsentHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine locally. I can see sometimes an error occurs and the ConsentHandler handles the exception and as a result OnInitializedAsync is called again and the second time the graph api call works correctly and the user is returned

However, when the site is deployed in azure this code doesn't work. When the excpetion is caught and passed to the ConsentHandler.HandleException this in turns raises its own exception

**System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'headers')**

[image]

Has any one else come across this error when calling ConsentHandler.HandleException?

To make matters more interesting the OnInitializedAsync() gets called multiple times as we are using the ServerPrerendered render mode in _Host.cshtml. The first time the code is called in Azure it does return the user correctly from the Graph call. But any subsequent calls all fail

Comment: As is often the way, after been stuck on this for a few days I found the answer almost immediately after posting this question. The problem for my turned out to be that I had Authentication turned on in the app service itself in Azure and at the same time had Azure AD configured as a connected service on the Blazor server project in Visual Studio. Turning off authentication on the web app in azure and relaying just on the settings in the project allowed things to work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the way, after been stuck on this for a few days I found the answer almost immediately after posting this question. The problem for my turned out to be that I had Authentication turned on in the app service itself in Azure and at the same time had Azure AD configured as a connected service on the Blazor server project in Visual Studio. Turning off authentication on the web app in azure and relaying just on the settings in the project allowed things to work correctly